# Fetch Id's that are related to a specific set of items, but not others

Tags: sql, teradata

Good morning all, apologies for the title... i had trouble simplifying the problem down to a line. My database platform is Teradata.

I am working w/ a table like the following (let's call it "t1")

```
+------------+----------------------------------------+
| Service_Id |                Product                 |
+------------+----------------------------------------+
|          1 | Traffic                                |
|          1 | Weather                                |
|          1 | Travel                                 |
|          1 | Audio                                  |
|          1 | Audio Add-on                           |
|          2 | Traffic                                |
|          2 | Weather                                |
|          2 | Travel                                 |
+------------+----------------------------------------+
```

I am trying to select service_id's that are related to the following products AND ONLY the following products: Traffic, Weather, Travel

"Service_Id = 1" does not apply here because while it has the required products, it also has an "audio" product related to it... so we have to leave it out. I was able to successfully do this through a series of temp (volatile) tables but it's feeling really hacky and I feel there's got to be a better way. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing stuff like that (find a subset/superset/exact match for a set of rows) in my training classes using pizzas :-)

There are several ways to get your result, but for an **exact** match the easiest way is a SUM using following logic:

```
SELECT service_id
FROM t1
GROUP BY 1
HAVING
   SUM(CASE WHEN Product IN ('Traffic', 'Weather', 'Travel') THEN 1 ELSE -1 END = 3
```

Comment: Thanks! I really like this solution and it performed great against an extremely large table.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Product` is unique for every `service_ID`.

```
SELECT  service_ID
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   Product IN ('Traffic', 'Weather', 'Travel') AND
        EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    tableName b
            WHERE   a.Service_ID = b.Service_ID
            GROUP   BY b.Service_ID
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = 3 -- <<== total number of products
        )
GROUP   BY service_ID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 3 -- <<== total number of products
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*demo is running under MySQL database, not sure if it will work on teradata*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c50f/1)